# Rendering error when changing theme

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-design-library

I've decided to start learning about android, but right from the start, whenever I try to change the theme in Android Studio, I get the following Rendering error:

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
- android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
```

Even if I don't change the theme, when I delete the default "Hello word" text, I get this error. Everything works as it should when I run AVD, but it doesn't in the preview tool. I have already read couple of posts about this but none of them worked.

I've tried:

1. adding "Base" in front of the theme name in styles.xml
2. Lowering the API
3. Updating some SDK tools
4. using the same version of project (23) as the API.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing Empty Activity instead of blank activity solves the problem.